# Bidirectional LSTM cells in TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow

My question is to define bidirectional LSTM cells (fw_cell and bw_cell) in tensorflow we shall define fw_cell and bw_cell independently or the same?

Comment: You can do both

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can create a function that defines each cell separately, you can use something like this:

```
def lstm_rnn_cell(num_units, dropout):
  _cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units,state_is_tuple = True)
  _cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(_cell, output_keep_prob = dropout)
  return _cell
```

and then you can do:

```
fw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_rnn_cell(rnn_size, dropout = dropout) for _ in range(num_layers)], state_is_tuple = True)
bw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell([lstm_rnn_cell(rnn_size, dropout = dropout) for _ in range(num_layers)], state_is_tuple = True)
```

in this example I used a `MultiRNNCell` so you can also define the number of layer for the given RNN by modifying `num_layers`

Comment: You are defining two independent forward and backward cells. This solution does not work in case you want to concatenate the outputs of forward and backward cells before feeding to next layer.

Comment: I guess the real question was should we define two independent cells or reuse the same cell (which means the same weights) for forward and backward directions?